# CSS grid - struggling with uneven columns

Tags: css, css-grid

Trying to style these columns and can't figure it out how to do this with CSS grid, either one or the other column always goes off the grid. Does anyone suggest a clean solution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

adding a `px` column in the middle and should work.

POC:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [c1] 1fr [c2] 30px [c3] 1fr [c4] 1fr [c5];
  grid-template-rows: [r1] 100px [r2] 100px [r3];
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px
}

div {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.a {
  grid-column: c1 / c2;
  grid-row: r1 / r2;
}

.b {
  grid-column: c2 / c4;
  grid-row: r1 / r2;
}

.c {
  grid-column: c4 / c5;
  grid-row: r1 / r3;
  background: black;
}

.d {
  grid-column: c1 / c3;
  grid-row: r2 / r3;
}

.e {
  grid-column: c3 / c4;
  grid-row: r2 / r3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
  <div class="e"></div>

</div>
```